# SeleniumRC FF3.5.x-3.6 lock file troubles

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

With Selenium RC 1.0.1, and FF3.5.x or 3.6 I keep seeing this error when trying to run any test,

> Failed to start new browser session:
>   Unable to delete file
>   \parent.lock

when running the server with either,

java -jar selenium-server.jar -multiwindow

or

java -jar selenium-server.jar

Any one found a way to run a selenium RC test against those version of FF?  Here's the full stack trace,

```
ERROR - Failed to start new browser session, shutdown browser and clear all session data
```

java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox refused shutdown while preparing a profile
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.wai
tForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:311)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.pop
ulateCustomProfileDirectory(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:106)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.lau
nch(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.lau
nchRemoteSession(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:350)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxLauncher.launchRem
oteSession(FirefoxLauncher.java:98)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.createNewRemoteSessi
on(BrowserSessionFactory.java:357)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession
(BrowserSessionFactory.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory.getNewBrowserSession
(BrowserSessionFactory.java:84)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.getNewBrowse
rSession(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:699)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.doCommand(Se
leniumDriverResourceHandler.java:393)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handleComman
dRequest(SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.java:364)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler.handle(Selen
iumDriverResourceHandler.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.mortbay.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.mortbay.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:
245)
        at org.mortbay.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
        at org.mortbay.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher$Fil
eLockRemainedException: Lock file still present! C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1.SPS\LOCALS
~1\Temp\customProfileDirf09f31ccacf4468385010edaecd5925d\parent.lock
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.wai
tForFileLockToGoAway(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:269)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher.wai
tForFullProfileToBeCreated(FirefoxChromeLauncher.java:309)
        ... 20 more
INFO - Got result: Failed to start new browser session: Unable to d
elete file C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1.SPS\LOCALS~1\Temp\customProfileDirf09f31ccacf446
8385010edaecd5925d\parent.lock on session null

Restarting the browser, and clearing the cache didn't help.  Using FF 3.0.x works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Seems seleniumRC 1.0.2 just came out today with claimed support for FF3.6 and such.  Is working for me.

Comment: SeleniumRC 1.0.3 fixed this for me. It's worth knowing that you need to look on http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list to find this version.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by following these instructions:

http://jira.openqa.org/browse/SRC-507

This is for an older version of Selenium, but it works just the same.  I am having to use 1.0.1 (for IE compatibility) and it has the MaxVersion of FF at 3.5.  It was throwing the same error as above.

I changed the various files to '3.6' and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded Selenium RC 1.0.3, and it did NOT fix the problem for me.